# Pass data from Gridview to new activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, parameter-passing

I have a problem in passing id number from the SQLite database to new second activity page. I think my passing id is null. But I don't know which part I need to correct. And I think it also related to String and ArrayList. The first coding is the main activity. Second coding is the second activity(ImageList). The third coding is CustomGridAdapter to the first page. the fourth coding is CustomGridAdapter1 to the second page. Anyone can correct my coding.

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        imageList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new CustomGridAdapter(this, R.layout.image_item, imageList);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // get all data from sqlite
        Cursor cursor = databaseAccess.getData("SELECT * FROM IMAGE");
        imageList.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cursor.getString(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(2);

            imageList.add(new Things(id, name, image));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
                view.setSelected(true);
                final Things labels=imageList.get(position);
                Intent passIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageList.class);
                passIntent.putExtra("keyid", String.valueOf(labels));
                startActivity(passIntent);

            }
        });
```

```js
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
       imageList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new CustomGridAdapter1(this, R.layout.image_general);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Bundle showData = getIntent().getExtras();
        rowId = showData.getString("keyid");
        databaseAccess = new DatabaseAccess(getApplicationContext());
        cursor = databaseAccess.getImage(rowId);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
            String id = cursor.getString(1);
            String name = cursor.getString(2);
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);
            String imgid = cursor.getString(4);

            General general =new General(id, name, image,imgid);
            adapter.add(general);
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

```js
public class CustomGridAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int layout;
//    private ArrayList<Things> ImageList;
    List ImageList= new ArrayList();

    public CustomGridAdapter(Context aContext,  int layout, List ImageList) {
        this.context = aContext;
        this.ImageList =ImageList;
        this.layout=layout;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ImageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return ImageList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView Thing;
        ImageView ThingImage;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
//            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridgeneral, null);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
            holder.ThingImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_flag);
            holder.Thing= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thing);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Things things= (Things) this.getItem(position);
        holder.Thing.setText(things.getName());

        byte[] thingName = things.getImage();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(thingName, 0, thingName.length);
        holder.ThingImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

```js
public class CustomGridAdapter1  extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int layout;
//    private ArrayList<General> ImageList;
    List ImageList= new ArrayList();

    public CustomGridAdapter1(Context aContext, int layout) {
        this.context = aContext;
        this.ImageList = ImageList;
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ImageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return ImageList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void add(General general) {
        ImageList.add(general);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView Thing;
        ImageView ThingImage;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
//            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridgeneral, null);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_general, null);
            holder.ThingImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_flag1);
            holder.Thing = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thing1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

//        General general = ImageList.get(position);
        General general=(General) this.getItem(position);

        holder.Thing.setText(general.getName());
        byte[] thingName = general.getImage();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(thingName, 0, thingName.length);
        holder.ThingImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: final Things labels=imageList.get(position). I assume 'Things' is an object. If you want to pass object to another activity, that object class should implement Parcelable. On your second activity, you can retrieve the object with getParcelableExtra() instead of getString()

Comment: How to implement the Parcelable in object class?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data from your one activity to other with data inside your POJO class object or model object then use GSON to convert your model to be transferred with intent.

```
Things labels=imageList.get(position);
```

You are trying to send the **label** to your next activity. So you wanna pass data between different activity however you are passing a custom object list which is not parseable using the putExtra function.

You can the use Gson+Type token to send your data.

Go through the following example:

Inside your model named **Things**.Add annotations to each private data.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Student{

   @SerializedName("student")
    private String student;
   @SerializedName("id")
    private int studentID;

      public Student(String student, int studentID){
         this.student = student;
         this.studentID = studentID;
      }
}
```

> **When passing data to intent, you need to first initialize a gson object and type for converting the your own object to json string.**

```
Things labels=imageList.get(position);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Things>() {}.getType();
String json = gson.toJson(labels, type);

 Intent passIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageList.class);
 passIntent.putExtra("keyid", json);
 startActivity(passIntent);
```

> > **Inside onCreate method of your next or target activity i.e In your
> >     case is ImageList.java**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String stringLocation = data.getStringExtra("keyid");
if(stringLocation != null) {
  Type type = new TypeToken<Things>>() {
   }.getType();
   Things label = gson.fromJson(stringLocation, type);
   Log.d("Data Recieved", label.getId());
}
else{
Log.d("Location Count","failed");
}
```

Comment: When i insert the serializable and gason it still become in red color. Do I need to import something?

Comment: Yes you need to add GSON library inside your grade file.